# call javascript object array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an object `window.Think` and an array:

```
window.Think.questions = [
  {answers: [
    {a: 1, b: 2}
  ]}
];
```

I'm trying to `.append()` part of this array into an element `.buttons` in my html.

How can I modify this so it prints part of my array?

```
$think = window.Think.new;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buttons").append($think.questions[1]);
});
```

Comment: you'll have to either stringify the array, or iterate over it creating text/html.

Comment: what do you want to append and in what format?

Comment: I want to take 1 and put it as the name of a checkbox. `<input type="checkbox" name="1">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to append

> A is: 1 -- B is: 2

with this exact data structure, you would do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $think = window.Think.questions;
    $(".buttons").append("A is: " + $think[0].answers[0].a + " -- B is: " +$think[0].answers[0].b);
});
```

EDIT:

I just saw your comment above... here is what you would need to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $think = window.Think.questions;
    $(".buttons").append('<input type="checkbox" name="' + $think[0].answers[0].a + '"/>');
    $(".buttons").append('<input type="checkbox" name="' + $think[0].answers[0].b + '"/>');
});
```

You probably want the `name` to be something different than just an integer... are you sure you don't mean `value`?

Answer (score 1):

As @KevinB pointed out, you will have to stringify the portions that you want to display in the button, for instance:

```
var answers = window.Think.questions[0].answers[0],
    values = [answers.a, answers.b].join(' ');// turn the array values into a space delimited string

$('.buttons').append(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your checkbox has an ID:

```
$('#cheboxID').attr('name', $think[0].answers[0].a);
```